# Django Custom 404 handler

Tags: python, django

We've recently upgraded to Django 1.10 and we're getting this error on the live site:

builtins:TypeError custom_404() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exception'

The code is as follows:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [ ... ]
handler404 = global_views.custom_404
handler500 = global_views.custom_500
```

**global_views.py**

```
def custom_404(request, exception, template_name='404.html'):
    return page_not_found(request, exception, template_name=template_name)   

def custom_500(request, template_name='500.html'):
    return server_error(request, template_name=template_name)
```

We've tried many variations of this view but all result in that error.

What's going wrong?

Comment: The server has been updated and restarted several times. The problem is showing up on our software analytics tool (NewRelic). I don't think it is a problem that clients are encountering, just something that is happening in the back-end. Just need to know what is triggering it!

Comment: I can not reproduce your error, have you tried those functions by adding `url(r'^test404/', global_views.custom_404)` into url.py to test the function directly?

Answer (score 6):

Your function should be defined as:

`def custom_404(request, exception=None, template_name='404.html'):`

Take me hours to figure this out.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.page_not_found

Answer (score 1):

The [`server_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view) view should not take `exception` as an argument. Its signature is

```
defaults.server_error(request, template_name='500.html')
```

It's not clear why you have defined a `custom_404` view if all you do is call `page_not_found`. And calling `page_not_found` in you `custom_500` view is very odd.

Comment: I pasted the custom_404 view as the custom_500 view for examples sake. My bad, will edit that... 

I wan't to use a custom template for my 404, and show different error templates according to the app.

Comment: To customize the 404 template just name your template `404.html`. From your question, it doesn't look like you need a custom 404 handler, and the code you have posted shouldn't cause that error. Maybe there's more useful information in the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for this. A much simpler solution was to remove the handlers and just let Django pick up on the 404.html file. However, I have three different apps which I would like different 404 pages for. Inserting a 404.html into the app's template folder does not seem to do the trick. It still renders the 404.html file from the root template folder. Any ideas about this?

Comment: If you want to chance the template dynamically, then setting a custom `handler404` sounds like a good approach.